# Can't export apk files in flash builder

Tags: android, apache-flex, apk, flash-builder

I'm developping a mobile application in Flash builder. So in Flash Builder Burrito , I was using the Flex Hero SDK 4.5.0 but they currently realesed the Flex4.5.0.20967.

I downloaded the zip file ( http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+4.5)

I extracted it into a map on my C:\ drive.
Then I opened my flash builder burrito. Added him by (Window>Flash Builder>Installed Flex SDK's. I his add and added my location.

This went very well. I changed my code with the new commands.

Next I wanted to test on my android phone but now my problem:
I can't make any apk files anymore. Does anybody knows how this comes and have a solution for this?

Hope someone can help me.

Kind regards,

Thibault Heylen

Comment: I have the same problem with ActionScriptMobile project. my compiled both through Export Functionnality and Command Line run a "[INSTALL FAILED INVALID APK]" but with a new Flex Mobile Project its work fine.... maybe some swc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash Builder Burrito was a preview version. It can only use Flex Hero. I think that I read somewhere that if you want to use the final version of Flex 4.5 you have to use the final version of Flash Builder 4.5

Comment: this bug is fixed using Flash Builder 4.5?

Comment: Yes this bug is gone I think. I installed the trial version of the new flash builder 4.5 and everything worked fine there. So if u use the new SDK you have to use the new flashbuilder

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly in Flash Builder 4.5, you can run it in Samsung Tab, or Nexus S but forget it in old devices...